# Where is the source code for Gadgeteer.StorageDevice?

Tags: .net-micro-framework, .net-gadgeteer

I'm trying to debug some unexpected behaviour with the [GHI Gadgeteer SDCard module](http://www.ghielectronics.com/catalog/product/271) whereby saving a file to an SDCard silently results in no file appearing.

The source code for the SDCard module is available (from [the root](http://gadgeteer.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/24955) navigate to [Main/Modules/GHIElectronics/SDCard/Software/SDCard/SDCard_42/SDCard_42.cs](http://gadgeteer.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/24955#256638)). The line in my code that's not doing what I expect is

```
sdCard.GetStorageDevice().WriteFile("picture.bmp", picture.PictureData);
```

Looking at the GHI source code `GetStorageDevice()` is simple:

```
public StorageDevice GetStorageDevice()
{
    return _device;
}
```

and `_device` is declared as

```
private StorageDevice _device;
```

Downloading the code I see that `_device` is of type `Gadgeteer.StorageDevice`. Where do I find the source code for that class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got [an answer on the TINYCLR forum](http://www.tinyclr.com/forum/topic?id=10838). It is in `Main/GadgeteerCore/Gadgeteer42/Utilities.cs` the current version (at the time of writing) is: http://gadgeteer.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/24955#200043

Answer (score 1):

### SD Card Module

You must first mount the `sdCard` before you can use it:

```
sdCard.MountSDCard();
```

To make sure you see this, you should "wire up" the Mounted and Unmounted event handlers beforehand, though:

```
void ProgramStarted() {
  sdCard.SDCardMounted += new SDCard.SDCardMountedEventHandler(sdCard_SDCardMounted);
  sdCard.SDCardUnmounted += new SDCard.SDCardUnmountedEventHandler(sdCard_SDCardUnmounted);
}

void sdCard_SDCardUnmounted(SDCard sender) {
  Debug.Print("The SD card has been unmounted");
  Debug.Print("DO NOT try to access it without mounting it again first");
}

void sdCard_SDCardMounted(SDCard sender, GT.StorageDevice SDCard) {
  Debug.Print("SD card has been successfully mounted. You can now read/write/create/delete files");
  Debug.Print("Unmount before removing");
}
```

If none of these are your problems, I would suggest breaking down your `GetStorageDevice()` call as follows:

```
string rootDirectory = sdCard.GetStorageDevice().RootDirectory;
// What format is `picture`?
// I am going to assume System.Drawing.Bitmap for this example.
picture.Save(rootDirectory + "\\picture.bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp;
```

If you can not use the [Bitmap.Save Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142147%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), you would use other conventional StreamWriter techniques.

I can not actually test this to see if it works, however, as I do not have one of these SD Card Modules. I just looked at the sample code on the [SD Card Module Tutorial](http://wiki.tinyclr.com/index.php?title=SD_Card_Module).

If it helps, vote it up. If it solves your problem, mark it as the answer.

Comment: +1 for the suggestions, though the tutorial you've copied from is for 4.1, and 4.2 is slightly different (e.g. I do not need to explicitly call MountSDCard). But I cannot mark it as the answer. The question was "Gadgeteer.StorageDevice. Where do I find the source code for that class?" Do you know the answer? If you edit that in I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: You may have to contact [GHI Electronics](http://www.ghielectronics.com/) directly for the source code. Would they share it? If they are a small company, they might. It never hurts to ask.

Comment: Gadgeteer is Open Source, and as I point out in the question they do share the code on CodePlex. I cannot find the code there for `Gadgeteer.StorageDevice`.